# Workbench moderation allowing a role to unpublish content?

Tags: users, workflows, workbench

I'm using [Workbench Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) on a new D7 site build.
All is great in terms of workflow and I think I have the permissions near perfect, but I can't for the life of me seem to grant my 'content approver' roles the ability to unpublish content.

If I log in as a administrator (Drupal default role) I can see the option to 'unpublish' appearing, but I can't spot a particular Workbench / Drupal permission to grant to allow this permission for lower roles.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make transitions for the backward states through moderation (eg, Published -> Needs Review, and Published -> Draft) on **admin/config/workbench/moderation/transitions**

[image]

Then, on  on **admin/people/permissions#module-workbench_moderation**, assign the permissions appropriately to the roles you want to allow to push things backwards

[image]